# Amazon ElasticSearch service Signature mismatch for PUT Request - Amazon SDK php V2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I am using Amazon ElasticSearch Service and when i tried to create SignatureV4 Request it is working fine for search operations (GET Requests). But when i tried to do some operations like create indices (Using PUT request), it will trough the Signature mismatch error.

I am using Amazon SDK version 2 SignatureV4 library for signing the requests. Also created a custom Elasticsearch handler to add tokens to the request.

Does anybody have such issue with SignatureV4 library in Amazon SDK php V2.

```
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the  service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'PUT\n/test_index_2\n\nhost:search-test-gps2gj4zx654muo6a5m3vxm3cy.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:XXXXXXXXXXXX\n\nhost;x-amz-date\n271d5ef919251148dc0b5b3f3968c3debc911a41b60ef4e92c55b98057d6cdd4'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\XXXXXXXXXXXX\n20170511/eu-west-1/es/aws4_request\n0bd34812e0727fba7c54068b0ae1114db235cfc2f97059b88be43e8b264e1d57'\n"}
```

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Yes @VladHolubiev i tried the same way they documented and it worked for GET operation like (search, find item etc..). But not for PUT operations.

Comment: If it works for one and not the other, then there's a subtle difference in the requests that is invalidating your logic.  The error message gives you some valuable troubkeshooting info, including the canonical request (which ends with the sha256hex payload hash) and the string-to-sign (which ends with the sha256hex hash of the canonical request).  Find the step in your signing process that generates the wrong result, and solve the problem occurring at that step.  It can only be there, not later, since wrong result at any step will always cascade out.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the issue was for PUT request the payload hash did not consider the request body. That leads to the invalid signature. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That would do it. I'm glad you found it.  Do you think there's an opportunity here to help future visitors by posting a useful/meaningful answer/solution?  For example, if could show the error page and how you used that info to step through your troubleshooting process... or you found something in the documentation that was ambiguous amd caused you to make a coding error... or should we close this as a problem that can no longer be reproduced? Or would you like to delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

This tweak only necessary for the users who are still using Amazon SDK PHP version 2. In version 3, it supported by default.

For signed request i updated the current elsticsearch client handler by adding a middle ware for signing the request.

```
$elasticConfig = Configure::read('ElasticSearch');
$middleware = new AwsSignatureMiddleware();
$defaultHandler = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::defaultHandler();
$awsHandler = $middleware($defaultHandler);

$clientBuilder =  \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create();
$clientBuilder->setHandler($awsHandler)
            ->setHosts([$elasticConfig['host'].':'.$elasticConfig['port']]);
$client = $clientBuilder->build();
```

I used the following library for this purpose

```
use Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface;
use Aws\Common\Signature\SignatureInterface;
use Guzzle\Http\Message\Request;

class AwsSignatureMiddleware
{
/**
 * @var \Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface
 */
protected $credentials;

/**
 * @var \Aws\Signature\SignatureInterface
 */
protected $signature;

/**
 * @param CredentialsInterface $credentials
 * @param SignatureInterface $signature
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $amazonConf = Configure::read('AmazonSDK');
    $this->credentials = new \Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials($amazonConf['key'], $amazonConf['secret']);
    $this->signature = new \Aws\Common\Signature\SignatureV4('es', 'eu-west-1');
}

/**
 * @param $handler
 * @return callable
 */
public function __invoke($handler)
{
    return function ($request)  use ($handler) {
        $headers = $request['headers'];
        if ($headers['host']) {
            if (is_array($headers['host'])) {
                $headers['host'] = array_map([$this, 'removePort'], $headers['host']);
            } else {
                $headers['host'] = $this->removePort($headers['host']);
            }
        }
        if (!empty($request['body'])) {
            $headers['x-amz-content-sha256'] = hash('sha256', $request['body']);
        }

        $psrRequest = new Request($request['http_method'], $request['uri'], $headers);
        $this->signature->signRequest($psrRequest, $this->credentials);
        $headerObj = $psrRequest->getHeaders();
        $allHeaders = $headerObj->getAll();

        $signedHeaders = array();
        foreach ($allHeaders as $header => $allHeader) {
            $signedHeaders[$header] = $allHeader->toArray();
        }
        $request['headers'] = array_merge($signedHeaders, $request['headers']);
        return $handler($request);
    };
}

protected function removePort($host)
{
    return parse_url($host)['host'];
}
}
```

The exact line i tweaked for this purpose is

```
if (!empty($request['body'])) {
    $headers['x-amz-content-sha256'] = hash('sha256', $request['body']);
}
```

For PUT and POST request the payload hash was wrong because i was not considering the request body while generating payload.

Hope this code is beneficial for anyone who is using Amazon SDK PHP version 2 and using the IAM based authentication for Elasticsearch Hosted service in Amazon cloud.